Firemonkey on Arm MAC SHow Components to big
I developoer and app on firemonkey, on Windows an Android show the GUI perfect.
On OSX Mac ARM show big and cant work with it.
THis is on IDE (Windows And Android)

And this how looks on the mac

Anyone can helpme

put all controls into a ScaledLayout

Without further information on what Delphi version you're using and on what MacOS version your app is running, not much can be suggested. Anyway you can check this thread for a good start: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-41928

I found it:
When i use a old Mac, everithing is fine.
On my Mac M1 just add:
GlobalUseMetal := True;
And thats it
